# How to Check Current Time with Restaurant Times on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to check the current local time with the restaurant's opening and closing time. I'm using Google Maps API and I have been able to show some restaurants on the map. The map centre is Adelaide, Australia, but the tool asks for the user location and goes there. I want to compare the time and if the time is not in between, the restaurant should not be on the map. Also, if the hours are not set for a restaurant, then the tool should display the restaurant all the time.

Here is the CSS and JavaScript code. I have removed the API key.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var infoWindow;
var gmarkers = [];
var map;


function initMap() {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,   
    center: {lat: -34.9285,lng: 138.6007}
    });


    if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        });
}

    var markers = [
        // A
         {coords:{lat:-34.92366, lng:138.567063}, content:'<p><strong>Abyssinian Restaurant</strong></p>', timing: {open: 1200, close: 1400}},
         // B
         {coords:{lat:-34.923885, lng:138.562042}, content:'<p><strong>British Raj</strong></p>', timing: {open: 0800, close: 1700}},
         {coords:{lat:-34.843645, lng:138.507653}, content:'<p><strong>Banyan Hotel Port Adelaide</strong></p>', timing: {open: 0900, close: 1900}},
    ];


    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        gmarkers.push(addMarker(markers[i]));
        bounds.extend(markers[i].coords);
    }
   // map.fitBounds(bounds);


    function addMarker(props) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: props.coords,
        map: map,
    icon:'Ellipse 1.png'});

    if (props.content){
        marker.addListener('click', function(){
        infoWindow.setContent(props.content);
        infoWindow.open(map,marker);});
        }


       return marker;

   }

}
</script>
<script src="markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 80%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your CSS (an extra closing `}`)

Comment: Where are you getting the open hours of the restaurant from?

Comment: I can get each manually using Google Maps or if there is a way to get the hours using Google Maps API.

Comment: They are available from the Places API (for some locations).  I don't see any "open hours" in the posted code. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish and where you are running into trouble.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how to implement that feature. My mind works, that I add two extra strings in marker and create a function to check if the current time is between the restaurant hours and then check every restaurant in already working loop. I'll make an example of what I can achieve and post that tomorrow.

Comment: The [Place Details Response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses) contains a field for `opening_hours`

Comment: I can get the hours manually, but I need a way to check if the local time is in between each restaurant's so if it is I can display the restaurant on the map. If the restaurant is closed (current time is not between the restaurant hours), then I don't want to show the restaurant on the map. I have updated the code. Each restaurant will have timing. I want to take that timing and compare with the local time. A Date object is also created in the addMarker method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your code as follows:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  const marker = addMarker(markers[i]);
  if (marker) {
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(markers[i].coords);
  }
}
// map.fitBounds(bounds);

function addMarker(props) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  const currentTime = parseInt(currentDate.getHours().toString() + currentDate.getMinutes().toString());
  if (props.timing.open > currentTime || props.timing.close < currentTime) {
    return false;
  }

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: props.coords,
    map: map,
    icon:'Ellipse 1.png'
  });

  if (props.content) {
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(props.content);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
  return marker;
}
```

My local time is 919 (09:19 AM) so only "Banyan Hotel Port Adelaide" and "British Raj" show up on the map, because "Abyssinian Restaurant" opens at 1200 (12:00 PM).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting an error on timing.open. The javascript error is Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Comment: It was a syntax error. Thanks very much for that. The solution is working. I have marked the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)